# Unable to create unordered_set with lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I get the error

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of '__compressed_pair_elem<(lambda at 
main.cpp:181:16), 1>': _Base1(std::forward<_Tp>(__t)), _Base2() {}
```

with the following code. What's the mistake I am making and I couldn't understand the error as well.

```
using namespace std;

auto my_hash = [](vector<int> const& vec){
    size_t seed = vec.size();
    for(auto& i : vec) {
        seed ^= i + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
    }
    return seed;
};

using MySet = unordered_set<vector<int>, decltype(my_hash)>;

int main() {
    vector<int> a{1,2,3};
    MySet s;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Closure types are not default-constructible prior to C++20 (see [P0624](http://wg21.link/p0624)). You need to pass in an instance of your hasher:

```
constexpr std::size_t bucket_count = 512;
MySet s{bucket_count, my_hash};
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lvNKTQzcx7L79uLV)

---

Alternatively, you can use a good old `struct`:

```
struct Hasher {
auto operator()(vector<int> const& vec) const {
    size_t seed = vec.size();
    for(auto& i : vec) {
        seed ^= i + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
    }
    return seed;
}
};

using MySet = unordered_set<vector<int>, Hasher>;

int main() {
    MySet s;
}
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6P0LhOplhgZSL3Us)

Comment: I am vaguely sad that that change also doesn't make trivial copyable capture lambdas trivial copyable in general.

Comment: When all can we not plugin lambda functions as functors directly? I remember we can plugin lambdas directly sometimes(like sort). @vittorio-romeo

Comment: @user3285099: when the type of the closure can be deduced

Comment: What does closure being deduced mean? I know close in the mathematics but couldn't understand in this context.

Comment: `[]{}` is a *lambda expression*, which produces a *closure* (object with `operator()`). The type of the closure is unique and anonymous, so you have to use `decltype` to retrieve it. In contexts such as function templates, the type can be deduced from the call site, so `decltype` is not required.